# Bind list of models as a property of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox, model-binding

I have a form which is sent to a controller in a strongly typed view.
The view is of a type "shitModel" which has a list of "shitType"

Model:

```
public class shitModel {
   public string name;
   public List<shitType> types;
}
```

View:

```
should contain listboxfor model.types
```

any ideas? thanks

Comment: By listbox you mean an HTML select box?

Comment: Check [HERE](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: the link you provided does not cover the list of complex object

Answer (score 0):

write following code on your view if it is a razor view

```
@*i am considering you have Name and ID members in your shitType class*@
@Html.DropDownList("shitTypes", Model.types.Select(t=> new SelectListItem{ Text = t.Name, Value = t.ID}))
```

Comment: But as the Value is id won't it save only List<string> and not the full shitType?

Comment: You mentiond shitType in your model :)
any ways you can achive that but having same String value for Text and Value properties.

Comment: but I don't need List<string>, I need List<shitType> I didn't undersatnd you